# Data structure for dynamic dropdowns that cascade

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, database-design

Ok, I'll probably be down-voted on this question but my heads not working and I can't come up with a neat solution.

Basically, I need to hold a series of dropdownlists in a database or xml file which will eventually be displayed and used on a page. Problem is I also need them to cascade and hold state after a form submission in MVC. Has anyone come across an example of this type of thing?

Comment: I do not think this is related with data structure. This is instead related to process logic IMO.

Comment: Its a bit of both Patrick really as I'm trying to figure out a nice reusable way to set up the parent child structure of the ddl items as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by cascading do you mean hierarchical+autofiltering?

maybe this is the data structure you need:
http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

autofiltering and "hold state" depends on the programming language.

Comment: Yes I do, I need to be able to create separate dropdowns but connect them neatly in a parent/child structure. The project is in MVC which doesnt hold state and that complicates things as if ddl2 is populated based on the selection from ddl1 using say jquery, I now need to filter the FormCollection to set ddl2's list again and set the correct item to selected in ddl2 on form submission (which just reloadsd the page and data on it dependent on the formcollection). Its all a bit messy

Comment: the the data structure I suggested fits your needs.
for the autopopulating of ddl2, just use ajax to query an action in one of the controllers which in turn queries that mptt table for the children of ddl1[element]